# Problem using package acronym

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sorting

I am using `acronym` package to create the list of Acronyms. I am using `Acronym1.tex` containing the definition of all the acronyms. However here is the list of problems I am facing.

1. I have to sort the list manually every time I need a sorted list in the pdf. I am not aware of the options with `usepackage`. I am currently using

   ```
   \usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
   ```
2. Is it possible to order the Acronym list? Currently what I am getting is

> <short>:<Description>..........<Page Number>

I would prefer something like this :

> <short>\t<Description>..........<Page Number>

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
In the early nineties,\ac{TDMA}, \ac{IEEE} , \ac{GSM}, \ac{WPAN} \ac{FPGA}

\section{Acronyms}
 \begin{acronym}
\acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\acro{WPAN}{Wireless Personal Area Network}
\acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\acro{FPGA}{Field Programmable Gate Array}
\acro{IEEE}{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

If you are using  `acronym` package and know the options on how to use it, that will be really helpful.

I could not find any relevant information, in [the documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the package `acronym` you can't sort the entries. Maybe you can write a small per-script. I recommend the package `glossaries` which is able to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{TDMA}{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\newacronym{WPAN}{WPAN}{Wireless Personal Area Network}
\newacronym{GSM}{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\newacronym{FPGA}{FPGA}{Field Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{IEEE}{IEEE}{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
In the early nineties,\ac{TDMA}, \ac{IEEE} , \ac{GSM}, \ac{WPAN} \ac{FPGA}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]
%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=altlistgroup]%alternative style
\end{document}
```

Now compile with

```
(pdf)latex
makeglossaries
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

Answer (score 6):

As you said, the `acronym` documentation doesn't mention "sorting" the acronym list. But a more telling fact is that it also doesn't mention either `makeindex` or `bibtex` which presumably would be used to sort a "raw" list of acronyms. Furthermore, in the discussion [acronym vs. glossaries](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/10e6871149cd00a7/d9ad10e602cb10d7?) at `comp.text.tex` it is stated that acronyms must be sorted *"manually in the input file"* when using `acronym`. Bottom line: If you want automatic acronym sorting, switch to a package like [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of the sorting part. I thought there is some options with \usepackage which I am missing. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty solution, export your list of acronyms from your `.tex`-file to calc/tables/excel or any other such program, sort the column, copy back to your `.tex`-file. The inconvenience is you have to remember to do that before your final compilation. It's not an eleganz solution, but if it is [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) you want to use, this is one of the most efficient ways to do it.

Alternatively, learn how to use the [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) or [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), like the others said. The [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package is newer than this question and has experienced a good 45 updates since it was first released. It is well maintained and well documented.

I use [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) right now, because I only do very basic things with it and [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) seemed overkill and would have required me to learn it and I don't have the time to do that right now. I still think it looks like a nice package and I plan to use it on my next project. It's especially way more useful, when use something else than English