# How can i get the abbreviations as list in Appendix page?

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

A possible list of terms, abbreviations and variable names with brief explanations has to be placed after the table of contents. If any term is explained in the list of terms, it is supposed to be used in the chapter text where it is used the first time. Is that possible in latex? If so which package can help me to do that. This MsWord screen shot is a good example..
[image]
thanks in advance..

Comment: You uses the tag `glossaries`. There is a package with the same name which I recommend. Many examples can be found on tex stackexchange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem using package acronym](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29348/problem-using-package-acronym)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package allows glossaries as well as lists of acronyms. Here's a full example (note: compile it with `pdflatex <myfile>` `makeglossaries <myfile>` `pdflatex <myfile>`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}

\textheight=180pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{svm}.

Some more text about \gls{svm}.

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

Some more text about \gls{electrolyte}.

\printglossary[type=acronym]

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I  am using TeXlipse in eclipse...could you suggest me how to compile this glosarry file here?

Comment: I don't know aynthing about TeXlipse. I'm using `latexmk` to run `makeglossaries`-- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries. If that isn't helpful, please ask a new question.

Comment: I am using everything what u said and successfully compiled with padflatex as u explained above..my .glo file empty..i dont get the problem..Am i missing something?

Comment: I get nothing too